# vba + copy sheet from one wb to another wb

Tags: vba, excel

This question is covered at many forums. I have the code, but it keeps saying error: mismatch. I have no idea why...

I've got 3 WB. the one with the macro that i'm writing now (1). One wb from wich the sheets needs to be copied (2) and then 1 wb to where the sheets needs to be copied to (3).

my code in (1): :

```
Dim sh As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("Sheet1").Select

PathNameOrigineel = Range("C2").Value
filenameOrigineel = Range("B2").Value

PathNameNew = Range("C3").Value
FilenameNew = Range("B3").Value

Set wbori = Workbooks.Open(PathNameOrigineel & filenameOrigineel)
Set wbNew = Workbooks.Open(PathNameNew & FilenameNew)

wbori.Activate
    For Each sh In wbori.Worksheets
        If sh.Name <> "Database" And sh.Name <> "Template" And sh.Name <> "Help" And sh.Name <> "OVERVIEW" And sh.Name <> "Develop" And sh.Name <> "Schedule" And sh.Name <> "Information" And sh.Name <> "Announcements" And sh.Name <> "Summary"        Then
        Sheets(sh).Copy After:=Workbooks(FilenameNew).Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: .Sheets(Sheets.Count) looks like your using the sheets from new file, but the sheets count on active file, could just use after wbNew.sheets.count.  WHat line does the error occur

Comment: hmm but the sheet has only one name at the time, I don't follow you

Comment: I removed it, I didn't see the <> at first, thought it was = not had a coffee yet.

Comment: :) I need the copied sheet in the new wb at the end. I thought it was with the command sheets.count. Do you know how I make sure the command counts the sheets form the second wb?

Comment: Step into your code with f8 and see what line the error is on.

Comment: it errors on the 'Sheets(sh).Copy After:=Workbooks(FilenameNew).Sheets(Sheets.Count)' line

Comment: try wbNew.sheets.count

Comment: Still gives an error: 'Run-time error 13: type mismatch'

Comment: Change `Sheets(sh).Copy` to `sh.Copy`

Comment: yes, you're using the sheet object, good spot Tim :)

Comment: Are your workbooks defined publicly? If not I would add `Dim wbori As Workbook, wbNew As Workbook`

Comment: I will add it, tx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sh` is already defined as a worksheet so you don't need `Sheets(sh).Copy`, just `sh.Copy`

```
For Each sh In wbori.Worksheets
    If sh.Name <> "Database" And sh.Name <> "Template" And sh.Name <> "Help" And sh.Name <> "OVERVIEW" And sh.Name <> "Develop" And sh.Name <> "Schedule" And sh.Name <> "Information" And sh.Name <> "Announcements" And sh.Name <> "Summary"        Then
    sh.Copy After:=Workbooks(FilenameNew).Sheets(wbNew.Sheets.Count)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Yeay, Now it works. The first time I tried sh.copy but it didn't work. Now I know that I needed to add wbNew.sheets.count. So thank you both (Tim wilkinson and Nathan_Sav) for the quick replies and the help!

Comment: @VeVi this is classis case to use `Select Case sh.Name` especially when you have so many `If`s

Comment: hi Shai Rado, Don't I need more expressions to use select case? In my case I need to do something in all the sheets that are not the one I use in my if structure. But i'm sure that if someone reviewed whole my code he/she would tear out his/her hair ^^.